# Windows 8 Metro monitor iframe navigtion

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, dom-events, microsoft-metro

I have a windows 8 metro app that does an oauth login via iframing the login form of the remote service. I need to monitor navigation in the iframe as the final step will navigate to a url that includes oauth codes I need to read out of the url.

There are 2 parts to this question:

1. How do I monitor navigation in the iframe.
2. How do I get the *current* location of the iframe. Everything I'm trying (`document.getElementById('theIframe').{src|contentWindow.location.href}`) either gives the initial location or returns an Access Denied error.

Comment: Is there are reason you are not using the WebAuthenticationBroker?

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT I guess I can do but it doesn't fit in well with the look and feel of the application. Is there any way to disable the requirement that the Broker urls require ssl, just for testing purposes. I'm hosting the oauth server locally right now and really don't want the hassle of installing a ssl cert on my dev box.

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT That WebAuthenticationBroker wasn't documented anywhere obvious. Would you like to add an answer with a link to the sample project and I'll accept it.  I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

As @JeffBrand-MSFT suggested, this sample may help.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122

Some documentation that maybe helpful
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker

To answer your original question, you can query the `.src` property in the iframe to monitor the `url`. (e.g. `var currentLocatoin = $('#iframeId').src`) or you can implement [`postMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441295.aspx) protocol between your native app and the content inside of the iframe. Mircrosoft sandboxed the iframe content, thus calling `$('#iframeId').contentWindow.location.href` will give you `Access Denied Error`

Comment: I found the various attributes (`src`, `contentWindow.location.href`) never actually update such that the parent can see them, my second point in the original Q.  I got this working with the WebAuthenticationBroker once I was put onto that, it just wasn't easy to find that info until pointed at it.

Comment: In my application where I have an iframe, I used the `postMessage` to query the location. But I wasn't using it for authentication.